# Adding fusioncharts with angularjs gives : inject modulerr error

Tags: angularjs, module, fusioncharts

I want to add fusioncharts to my angularjs app. I have followed this link:

http://www.fusioncharts.com/blog/2015/03/angular-fusioncharts/

But as soon as I add ng-fusioncharts to my app.js as:

```
      var app = angular.module('myApp',['ngRoute', 'firebase','ng-fusioncharts']);


       app.config(function($routeProvider){
      $routeProvider
     .when('/', {
    controller: 'OrgListController',
    templateUrl: 'views/organization/list.html'
})

.when('/add_org', {
    controller: 'OrgAddController',
    templateUrl: 'views/organization/org_add.html'
})
.when('/edit_org/:id', {
    controller: 'OrgEditController',
    templateUrl: 'views/organization/org_edit.html'

})
.when('/add_access_point', {
    controller: 'AccessPointAdd',
    templateUrl: 'views/access_points/access_add.html'
})
.when('/edit_access_point/:id', {
    controller: 'AccessPointEdit',
    templateUrl: 'views/access_points/access_edit.html'

})
.when('/add_user', {
    controller: 'UserAdd',
    templateUrl: 'views/users/user_add.html'
})
.when('/edit_user/:id', {
    controller: 'UserEdit',
    templateUrl: 'views/users/user_edit.html'

})

.otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/'
});
```

});

Nothing gets displayed and my whole project doesn't work. Viewing in console says :

```
                 error: inject modulerr.................
```

Somebody please suggest how to add multiple dependencies in one module?

Comment: Hove you found a solution to this problem? Can you provide it to us? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to have fusion-chart.js inorder to inject `ng-fusioncharts`

```
var app = angular.module('HelloApp', ["ng-fusioncharts"])
```

**[`DEMO`](http://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/bezbrq5g/)**

Comment: I already have fusion-chart.js, the problem is when adding multiple dependencies for module 'myApp'

Comment: what do you mean by multipled dependencies?

Comment: It means adding this ng-fusioncharts with ngRoute like this " var app = angular.module('myApp',['ngRoute', 'firebase','ng-fusioncharts']);
"

Comment: did you get any answer?

Answer (score 0):

This error can also occur if you have tried to add your own components to the ng module. This has never been supported and from 1.3.0 it will actually trigger this error. For instance the following code could trigger this error.

```
angular.module('ng').filter('tel', function (){});
```

Instead create your own module and add it as a dependency to your application's top-level module.

```
<html>
<head>
    <!-- Including AngularJS -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.2/angular.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Including the fusioncharts core library -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.fusioncharts.com/fusioncharts/latest/fusioncharts.js"></script>
    <!-- Including the angularjs-fusioncharts directive-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/angularjs-fusioncharts@4.0.1/dist/angular-fusioncharts.js"></script>
    <!-- Including the fusion theme -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.fusioncharts.com/fusioncharts/latest/themes/fusioncharts.theme.fusion.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ng-fusioncharts']);
        //STEP 2 - Chart Data
        const chartData = [
            { label: 'Venezuela', value: '290' },
            { label: 'Saudi', value: '260' },
            { label: 'Canada', value: '180' },
            { label: 'Iran', value: '140' },
            { label: 'Russia', value: '115' },
            { label: 'UAE', value: '100' },
            { label: 'US', value: '30' },
            { label: 'China', value: '30' }
        ];

        // STEP 3 - Chart Configurations
        const dataSource = {
            chart: {
                caption: "Countries With Most Oil Reserves [2017-18]",
                subCaption: "In MMbbl = One Million barrels",
                xAxisName: "Country",
                yAxisName: "Reserves (MMbbl)",
                numberSuffix: "K",
                theme: "fusion",
            },
            // Chart Data - from step 2
            "data": chartData
        };
        myApp.controller('MyController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
            // datasource
            $scope.myDataSource = dataSource
        }]);
    </script>

</head>

<body ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="MyController">
<div fusioncharts id="my-chart-id" width="700" height="400" type="column2d" dataSource="{{myDataSource}}">
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

TO know more about this feature please refer - https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/getting-started/angular/angularjs/your-first-chart-using-angularjs